# VBA. Ошибка во время вставки столбцов(Range.Insert) после Break mode

Tags: excel, vba, range, break

Всем привет. Возникла проблема при попытке вставить столбцы.

Если с нуля запустить Ехель и потом запускать этот макрос (код ниже), то все проходит на ура. Книга создается, заполняется и столбцы вставляются.

Если же включить BreakMode (Ctrl+Pause Break) и запустить макрос, то при вставке столбцов выдает "Run-time error '1004': application-defined or object-defined error"

Как с этим бороться?
Или хотя бы есть этому какое-то объяснение?

Заранее спасибо.

P.s. Юнион уже пробовал, да, как вариант, но слишком туговат да и RngInsert всегда генерируется.

**UPD.** Если же после того, как появилась ошибка, в переменной RngInsert указать диапозон столбцов без перечисление через запятую, например просто "H:H", то вставляет без ошибки.

```
Sub testinsert()

Dim RWS As Object
Dim RngInsert As String

Set RWS = Workbooks.Add.ActiveSheet 'Создание новой книги и сет листа
RngInsert = "G:G,H:H" 'Столбцы, которые нужно вставить

RWS.[a1:m10] = "test" 'Внесение данных
RWS.Range(RngInsert).Insert 'Вставка столбцов

Set RWS = Nothing 'Чистка переменной

End Sub
```

Comment: *Если же включить BreakMode (Ctrl+Pause Break) и запустить макрос, то при вставке столбцов выдает "Run-time error '1004': application-defined or object-defined error"* Не могу воспроизвести. Опишите подробнее, как. PS. Процедура - в common-модуле?

Comment: @Akina
Вот пример: https://youtu.be/32hGHPzQeiE
Запускаю первый раз - все норм. Включаю-выключаю брэйкмод и снова запускаю - ошибка.

Answer (score 0):

Как оказалось после Pause Break, Range перестает реагировать на разделитель диапазонов в виде запятой и воспринимает уже точку с запятой.
Ответ был дан на [соседнем форуме](https://www.planetaexcel.ru/forum/index.php?PAGE_NAME=read&FID=1&TID=133416&TITLE_SEO=133416-oshibka-vo-vremya-vstavki-stolbtsovrangeinsert&tags=mid&order=desc)